# variable is claimed to be undefined in error message, yet the variable works just fine

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I created a program to change the greyscale value of the background by tracking the `mouseX` position and mapping it unto the greyscale range, so that when I move the mouse left and right the color changes from black to white respectively.

I want to track the greyscale value as I move the mouse about, by calling the `print()` command upon clicking the mouse using `function mousePressed()`

When I run the program, the background color changes exactly as intended, meaning that the variable `z` is being calculated just fine, yet upon mouse click nothing prints and an error message is received: "p5.js says: There's an error due to "z" not being defined in the current scope."

**WHAT I KNOW:**

- tracking `mouseX` by printing it to console with `print()`, upon mouse click using `function mousePressed()` works fine, as I had used it successfully in a different program I made. even just switching the variable `z` inside the `print()` command to `mouseX` works.

**WHAT ELSE I TRIED:**

- I created a new variable, set its value to `z` and tried printing the new variable... didnt work.
- I mapped the size of the canvas to the greyscale range (0-255) manually by division of the two numbers,  and multiplied that by `mouseX` variable name - `ratio`. when I tried to print `ratio` the same problem occurred.

**WHAT DO I WANT AN ANSWER TO?:**

1. Why does this error occur upon calling either the mapped variable, and the manually calculated one?
2. How can I make this idea of clicking at any given mouse position, to receive the current greyscale value work? (preferably without calling any straightforward function like `background.color` or something)
3. This is my first question on this website and I tried to make it as readable as possible. I would like to receive some feedback on my question, was it easy to understand? was it too descriptive? and whatever else you might see appropriate and helpful for further question uploading.

**CODE:**
https://editor.p5js.org/KaliPali/sketches/uVx_T9kH5

```js
var frame = {  //this is used to save the canvas size and use it
  x: 600,
  y: 400
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(frame.x, frame.y);
}

function draw() {
  var z = map(mouseX, 0, frame.x, 0, 255) // first attempt. doesnt work
  //var ratio = mouseX*255/frame.x; //manual mapping attempt. doesnt work
  background(z);
  rectMode(CENTER)
  rect(mouseX,200,10,60)
}

function mousePressed() {
print('greyscale value is: ' + z)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: *some feedback on my question* Better presented than the vast majority of new questions we see, thanks! :)

Comment: A variable name which is declared can only be seen by other statements in its current scope and descendant blocks. The problem here is that you declare `z` inside your `draw` function (which means that `z` is visible everywhere inside `draw`), but nothing outside the function can see the variable name, so `mousePressed` can't see the `z` variable. You can fix it by declaring `z` outside the function, so that both `draw` and `mousePressed` can see it: `var z; function draw() { z = map(...);`